# How to append properties to geojson file in python?

Tags: python, json, data-visualization, geojson

For example i have geojson file with features as shown below.

{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "working_width": 20,
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          28.4766,
          12.5645456
        ]
      }
    }
]

How to add the properties to this above file as shown below.

{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "working_width": 20,
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          28.4766,
          12.5645456
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "fieldID": "2115145",
        "segmentId": "255c2s4c",
        "speed": 21.4586954,
        "elevation": 52.4586642,
        "time": "2018-05"
      }
    }
 ]
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data structure is just a regular python dictionary so you can update it as normal:

```
>>> geojson 
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'working_width': 20,
 'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
               'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 
                            'coordinates': [28.4766, 12.5645456]}}]}

>>> geojson['properties'] =  {'fieldID': '2115145', 
                              'segmentId': '255c2s4c', 
                              'speed': 21.4586954, 
                              'elevation': 52.4586642, 
                              'time': '2018-05'}

>>> geojson
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'working_width': 20,
 'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
               'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 
                            'coordinates': [28.4766, 12.5645456]}}],
 'properties': {'fieldID': '2115145',
                'segmentId': '255c2s4c',
                'speed': 21.4586954,
                'elevation': 52.4586642,
                'time': '2018-05'}}
```